# Как получить объект соседнего активити?

Tags: java, android

Создаю несколько активити, а объекты на них храню в классе, порождённом от класса приложения в виде статических переменных:

```
public class AppGlobal extends Application {
    static LoginActivity loginActivity = null;
    static MainActivity mainActivity = null;
    static FuncActivity funcActivity = null;
}
```

Теперь я могу, например, из mainActivity обращаться к loginActivity так:

```
AppGlobal.loginActivity
```

Такой подход был временный во время изучения программирования под Андроид. И возникает вопрос: правильный ли это подход? Наверняка, можно работать без такого глобального класса и статических переменных?

Comment: нет не правильно.

Comment: Как тогда обратиться к свойствам активити из другой активити?

Comment: Какие такие свойства "другой активити"?

Comment: Например, я закрывал другое активити из текущего: AppGlobal.activity2.finish();

Comment: И что получить то надо от него? Вообще закрывать активити ВАМ не надо - их без вас "закроют", когда возникнет такая надобность. Или зачем вы их сами закрываете?

Answer (score 3):

Нет, не правильный это подход. Совсем не правильный.

К другим активити, их методам, свойствам и чему бы то ни-было нельзя обращаться напрямую из текущей активити потому, что других активити, условно говоря, не существует (о утечках памяти, которые тоже никуда не денутся, уже сказал уважемый @[katso](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6520/katso)).
То есть, теоретически они могут и существовать какое-то время, но их существование не гарантируется системой, соответственно, когда они будут утрачены (уничтожены для очистки памяти под другие нужды) предсказать невозможно и все это приведет к тому, что приложение упадет в самый непредсказуемый момент.

Для коммуникаций между активити существует система интентов, ресиверов и паттерн метода обратного вызова (колбэк). Так же существуют библиотеки для коммуникаций между частями приложения, вроде *EventBus* или *Otto*

Answer (score 1):

Статические переменные, хранящие состояние, ведут к утечкам памяти, а если утекает активити, то утекает все, что в ней есть. К тому же вы можете обратиться к уже разрушенной активити.

Comment: Как тогда обратиться к свойствам активити из другой активити?

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте объекты между разными активити [с помощью Intent](http://www.startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/132-urok-69-peredaem-parcelable-obekty-s-pomoschju-intent.html), или же, если вам нужен не сам объект, а просто доступ к свойствам одной активити из другой - реализуйте в первой активити функцию и вызывайте эту функцию из второй активити. [Например так.](http://javatalks.ru/topics/44959?page=1#230636)

Comment: вообще, по второй ссылке речь идет про синглтон, а не про вызов функций одной активити из другой. Не будем сейчас углубляться в то, что синглтон сам по себе антипаттерн, все же это гораздо лучшее решение, чем обращаться к "функциям" в пустоту второй активити, за существование которой не сможет поручиться никто.

Comment: Исправил вторую ссылку.

Comment: Скажите каким образом вы предлагаете (из примера по второй ссылке) из одной активити, которая сейчас отображается, показывать какие то тексты в другой, которой,очевидно, не видно на экране. Пример по ссылке, даже если закрыть глаза на очевидную нелепость решения, очень плохая практика - так нельзя делать, если ваше приложение вам дорого и вам не все равно, что о нем подумают пользователи. Подобное решение еще возможно для коммуникаций: Хост-активити - фрагмент, но никак не между разными активити.