# Можно ли указать приложению не удалять активити из памяти?

Tags: java, android

> Теоретически активити могут существовать какое-то время, но их существование не гарантируется системой, соответственно, когда они будут утрачены (уничтожены для очистки памяти под другие нужды) предсказать невозможно и все это приведет к тому, что приложение упадет в самый непредсказуемый момент.

Можно ли указать приложению не удалять активити из памяти?

Comment: Этого не нужно делать для решения каких бы то ни было задач, потому, что это не соответствует архитектуре андроид-приложения. Не надо придумывать велосипеды с треугольными колесами только из-за того, что вы не знаете, как сделать правильно. Опишите задачу, которую вы пытаетесь решить, а не просите советы по вашим неправильным способам решения.

Comment: И не нужно плодить вопросы по одной проблеме, редактируйте один вопрос, если он требует уточнения.

Answer (score 2):

Правильный ответ: нельзя.

> и все это приведет к тому, что приложение упадет в самый непредсказуемый момент.

А вот это высказывание неверно. Если все делать как надо, ничего не упадет.

Comment: Это [цитата без контекста](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457467/177345). Речь идет о обращении к одной активити из другой и почему так не надо делать.