# Как обновить ListView из кастомного SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, cursoradaper

У меня есть *ListView* связанный с **БД** через *MySimpleCursorAdapter* (`extends android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter`)
И свой файл разметки, в котором есть кнопка удалить.
Я хочу при нажатии на кнопку удалить строку из **БД** и тут же обновить *ListView*.

Всю логику нажатия на кнопку я реализую в *MySimpleCursorAdapter*.

Как мне обновить *ListView* находясь в *MySimpleCursorAdapter*?

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    ......


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView IV_delete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_imageView_delete_note);
        .....
        IV_delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
...
        case R.id.item_imageView_delete_note:
                    Log.d(MainActivity.MY_TAG, "delete" + getItemId(lposition));
                    MainActivity.db.delete_row(getItemId(lposition));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Когда это `CursorAdapter` попал в библиотеку поддержки для виджетов ...

Comment: @pavlofff, прошу прощения, в разработки совсем недавно, но чем отличается  android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter от android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: @pavlofff сейчас изменю на android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: Да, это непринципиально в общем то. Я просто даже не знал, что в библиотеке поддержки есть тоже `CursorAdapter`

Comment: Работать с БД через класс активити [смертельно опасно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457467/177345) для приложения. Вам необходимо создать отдельный класс для работы с БД, который будет заниматься только этой самой работой и ни чем больше. Потом вам нужно ознакомиться с [принципами SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(объектно-ориентированное_программирование)) (особенно с S в вашем случае - единственной обязанности)

Comment: @pavlofff, у меня есть класс DB, в нем я создаю базу и описываю основные методы работы с базой(удаление, добавление и тд), и через экземпляр класса DB я и удаляю в своем MySimpleCursorAdapter. Это является нарушением принципов SOLID?

Comment: Вот эта строка `MainActivity.db.delete_row(getItemId(lposition));` вы обращаетесь к методу в активити из адаптера. Так не рекомендуется делать. Для манипуляций с БД обращайтесь непосредственно к экземпляру класса работы с БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы обновить список, подключенный к адаптеру на основе `CursorAdapter`, нужно вызвать метод [`changeCursor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)) - он информирует адаптер, что данные в курсоре изменились и нужно перестроить список используя новые данные.

Вызвать данный метод можно непосредственно в любом другом методе или конструктуре класса адаптера:

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
......


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView IV_delete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_imageView_delete_note);
        .....
        IV_delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
...
        case R.id.item_imageView_delete_note:
                    Log.d(MainActivity.MY_TAG, "delete" + getItemId(lposition));
                    MainActivity.db.delete_row(getItemId(lposition));
                    changeCursor();
    }   
}
```

так и "извне" - обратившись к экземпляру вашего адаптера, подключенного к списку:

```
MySimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(...);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
....
myAdapter.changeCursor(); // обновить список
```

Comment: Спасибо! НО, `notifyDataSetChanged();` мне не помогло, но об этом говорят [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985955/android-simplecursoradapter-doesnt-update-when-database-changes).

Comment: Мне помогло
`MySimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(...);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);`

Comment: Так вы просто создаете новый экземпляр адаптера, он конечно отрисует список по актуальным данным, но это не обновление списка, а создание нового.

Comment: Исправил ответ на основе ответов по вашей ссылке. Так список будет обновляться.

Answer (score 3):

1.Испольозвать CursorLoader.

2.Можно просто обновить и свапнуть курсоры.

```
private Db mDbAdapter;
private Cursor mCursor;
private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAd;

.....................................
//After removing the item from the DB, use this
.....................................

 mCursor = mDbAdapter.getAllItems();
 mCursorAd.swapCursor(mCursor);
```